# SDL with Code::Blocks and Visual Studio 2008 VC++ Compiler

Tags: visual-studio, linker, sdl, codeblocks

I've looked around on Google for tutorials on setting up SDL with it. The problem is that all the tutorials for linking to SDL with Code::Blocks is with the Mingw compiler, and never with VC++ 2008 Compiler.

I have the SDL for VS downloaded at C:\SDL. The problem is, I can't get it to work with Code::Blocks.

What do I need to do? I tried following the tutorials for Mingw but they don't seem to work.

Comment: Why would you use Code::Blocks with the vc++ compiler?? O.o

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial covers setting up SDL to work with Visual Studio .NET. I followed along with Visual Studio 2008 and found it fairly intuitive:

<del>http://pgdc.purdue.org/sdltutorial/sdl_setup.html</del> *(broken link)*

As the person who commented on your question implied, more information would be useful.